# I am unable to get my Javascript getMaxLetter problem to show correct results

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

*Hi! for my class I had to create a javascript function that returns a maxCharacter and how many times it shows up. -- The problem is this function will print out how many times the maxCharacter shows up but not print "maxChar" only "max" will print out. Here is the function:*

```
const getMaxLetter = (str) => {
    let max = 0;
    let maxChar = '';

    str.split('').forEach((char) => {
      if (str.split(char).length > max) {
      max = str.split(char).length;
      maxChar = char;
    }
  });
  return `The max letter is : ${maxChar} and the max number of times it is seen is: ${max}`;
};
```

Comment: Kinda worked for me:  Showed the correct letter, but +1 on count.

Answer (score 0):

Your "max char" is a space... just add

```
if (char === ' ') return;
```

```js
const getMaxLetter = (str) => {
    let max = 0;
    let maxChar = '';

    str.split('').forEach((char) => {
      if (char === ' ') return;
      if (str.split(char).length - 1 > max) {
        max = str.split(char).length - 1;
        maxChar = char;
      }
  });
  return `The max letter is : ${maxChar} and the max number of times it is seen is: ${max}`;
};

console.log(getMaxLetter('Abcde f ghhai f kh f k'))
```